Modals verbs. How to use "can"
I was taught that when we talk about possibility "can" is only for general one and "might,may, could" for specific one. Although, in my book I found these examples " Who can that be at this time of night? It can be Steve"
Why is that? Why not may might or could since it's a specific possibility. Is my book wrong? Please explain

Asking for proofreading ("Are my examples correct?") is off-topic for this site. Please [edit] and rephrase your question to be about the use of "can".

"It can be Steve" is not a natural reply to "Who can that be?", and if your textbook says so it is wrong. We would say "It might be Steve", "It could be Steve" or "Perhaps it's Steve".

But it's ok to use "can" in a question?

I'm sure I've seen a question about this before but can't find it. Anyway "Who can it be?" "Who can be calling at this time?" are conventional English ways of asking this sort of question. That's just the way it is. (Although you could also use "could").

But we don't answer with "can" ? We rather use migh may or could?

I personally don't think that can is used correctly in your example, but you can use may might or could.

Who can that be? It may be Steve.
Who can that be? It might be Steve.
Who can that be? It could be Steve.

If you turn it into a question, you can use can:

Who can that be? Can it be Steve?

You can also use can't. This is an example of informal, sarcastic or playful speech where the person already knows that it is Steve:

Who can that be? It can't be Steve!


Using can, may, might, could.
OP's question is about the use of these modals - Can, may, might, could

Who can that be at this time of night? It can be Steve"
Why is that? Why not may might or could since it's a specific possibility. Is my book wrong? Please explain.

Please note that using any of these modals in the question doesn't matter much -
Who can/could/ may/ might be?
But when we use this in the answer, there is much difference.
It could be/ maybe be/ might be/ will be Steve.
Ref Adventures with Grammar and Composition, Beena Sugatham. Oxford Printing Press.

We can also use may or might to show probability or possibility. May indicates a good possibility and might, a weak possibility though there is very little difference. We have already seen how *could" suggests possibility. It expresses still weaker possibility than might.
Must and will can also be used to indicate certainty or likelihood.
Must expresses a logical certainty and is used in a context stronger than may.
Will is used when we are one hundred per cent sure.



Read the dialogue. Study the use of may, might, could, will and must.
RAHUL: Where is Mohit?
MOHAN: He may be at the canteen.
JAYA: He might be in the library; we have to submit our English essays tomorrow.
SHALINI: He could be at the school office.
GAURAV: No, the basketball team is practising, since he is the captain of the team, he must be in the gymnasium now.
MOHAN: That is right, other basketball players are there. He will be there.

